# How to redraw only a portion of the presenting framebuffer?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

I want to implement a simple paint feature on iOS.
I have some framebuffers/textures wired up to get the desired final composition.

Redrawing the whole screen is a huge overhead. I can determine a rectangle that has changed.

So what is the best way to draw only that portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glScissor(0, 0, 50, 50);
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);